# Difference between ask and tell in Akka?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka

Reading the Scala doc I am having difficulty understanding the difference between ask and tell.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html states :

> ! means “fire-and-forget”, e.g. send a message asynchronously and
>   return immediately. Also known as tell.
>
> ? sends a message asynchronously and returns a Future representing a
>   possible reply. Also known as ask.

If the actor I'm using spawns a web request then what is the difference between ask and tell ? In both cases the request will be spawned asynchronously and must wait for a response, in other words how can "tell" return immediately if the actor is invoking a web service and awaiting a response ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you already know the basic difference between `ask` and `tell`, but don't understand how `tell` could be used to involve other actors in handling HTTP requests.

In order for it to make sense to use `tell` in your HTTP request handlers, you have to use an HTTP server that does not require that request handlers *return* their responses.  [Spray](http://spray.io/) is such an HTTP server.

In Spray a request handler does not return its response; it is given a RequestContext object, and responding to the request involves invoking some method on it.  You can simply send that RequestContext to another actor, which can then respond to the request:

```
path("foo") {
  rc => rc complete "foo"  // respond here
} ~
path("bar") {
  rc => barActor ! DoBar(rc)  // send it to bar; NO RESPONSE HERE
}
```

Then the actor referred to by barActor could say

```
case DoBar(rc) =>
  rc complete "bar"  // respond here, in another actor
```

The fact that Spray packages up the request context into an object that can be passed around and completed from any actor is a great fit for the actor model.  If, on the other hand, your web framework requires that the invoked handler return the response, then if you want to involve another actor your only choice is to use `ask`.

Typesafe announced that `Play` will soon use Spray underneath.  I hope that means that `Play` will then allow requests to be sent along to other actors for processing.

Comment: it's my understanding that Tomcat also processes requests asynchronously and all modern web servers process requests asynchronously , it they did not is it not very easy for requests to just queue up and cause slow server response times ?

Comment: If you mean that they allow you to process requests "asynchronously from one another" then sure -- a lot do that.  What I'm referring to here is whether the HTTP server invokes the handler as a method which is required to return the response as its result.  In that case a separate actor cannot handle the response; the handler would have to invoke the actor using ask, getting a Future for the result.  When the result arrives, the original handler would run again to handle the response.

Comment: Could you elaborate (or add links) about the design of system using tell? it seems like in "tell" design, if the request is some http, the second actor should know the structure of the response. in other words it looks like you delegate a web-interface into the application instead of separating them. another problem is if I need to compose 2 responses I will need either ask or I will need the first called actor to know to "tell" to a second one. Thanks.

Comment: found this for now http://bartoszsypytkowski.com/dont-ask-tell-2/ .  .NET but the idea seams to be relevant for all implementations

Answer (score 17):

The difference between `ask` and `tell` is from the point of view of the message sender (which is not necessarily an actor). `ask` will send the message  and return a future, which can be awaited until timeout or a reply is received, `tell` will send the message and return immediately.

In the case of `ask`, the actor that receives the message should reply to the sender when the operation is completed.

Comment: if tell returns immediately from a process which takes for example 30 seconds to return then what does it return ? Or is the difference tell is used where not to expect a return value wheras ask is used when a return value is expected at some point in time ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Both return immediately -- tell returns `Unit`, that is to say nothing, so no return value is expected. `ask` returns a `Future[Any]`, which can be `await`ed, or piped to another actor, or `map`ped to a callback to execute. `ask` is a lot more complicated, and is implemented via an implicit conversion to `akka.pattern.AskableActorRef`